# 14 Dodge Dart overheated

Tags: coolant, dodge, overheating, power-loss

My son’s car ran hot a month ago and he said it lost power. Car was towed in radiator hose had came off they replaced that oil still looked good. The next day it ran hot again this time they replaced the thermostat. The next day the temp dropped from 175 to -40 while he was driving. On his way home from work it started overheating again an emergency message flashed on his dashboard engine light came on he pulled over and turned it off. Any suggestions as to what is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm thinking (unfortunately) there's a larger issue which was caused by the initial overheat. The engine is probably damaged and is causing it to overheat again.

Comment: has someone checked the water pump?